# freezed loop curl without any errors

Tags: php, curl

See this sample code and output.
I run it via cmd on windows.
This code works well, but after some days, freezed and stopped output!
You can see last line of this log, there are not any error or signs!
I was confused as to what could be the cause!

```
do {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=151313&Flow=0');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Connection: keep-alive';
    $headers[] = 'Cache-Control: max-age=0';
    $headers[] = 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1';
    $headers[] = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36';
    $headers[] = 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9';
    $headers[] = 'Referer: http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=151915';
    $headers[] = 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate';
    $headers[] = 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fa;q=0.8';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($ch) . PHP_EOL;
    }
    if (!$result) {
        echo 'Error: No Result.' . PHP_EOL;
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    
    sleep(60);
}while(true);
```

output:

```
*   Trying 185.117.206.245:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.tsetmc.com (185.117.206.245) port 80 (#0)
> GET /Loader.aspx?ParTree=151313&Flow=0 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.tsetmc.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Referer: http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=151915
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fa;q=0.8

* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: public, no-cache="Set-Cookie"
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Encoding: gzip
< Expires: Sat, 12 Sep 2020 14:33:49 GMT
< Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=wrqiwgu5u115153ia15ohd4a; path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
< Date: Sat, 12 Sep 2020 14:33:40 GMT
< Content-Length: 15623
<
* Connection #0 to host www.tsetmc.com left intact

*   Trying 185.117.206.245:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* After 2499ms connect time, move on!
* connect to 185.117.206.245 port 80 failed: Timed out
*   Trying 185.117.204.245:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.tsetmc.com (185.117.204.245) port 80 (#0)
> GET /Loader.aspx?ParTree=151313&Flow=0 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.tsetmc.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Referer: http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=151915
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fa;q=0.8

* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: public, no-cache="Set-Cookie"
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Encoding: gzip
< Expires: Sat, 12 Sep 2020 14:34:59 GMT
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
< Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=f5qzrtaopkuhn0q3yjy5h3vx; path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Sat, 12 Sep 2020 14:34:51 GMT
< Content-Length: 15623
<
```

```
C:\>php -v
PHP 7.2.31 (cli) (built: May 12 2020 10:26:30) ( NTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x64 )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.31, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

**EDIT:**
I tried this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64512531
And the result is:

```
:
:
:

2020-11-03 -  5:29:24
*   Trying 185.117.204.245:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.tsetmc.com (185.117.204.245) port 80 (#0)
> GET /Loader.aspx?ParTree=151313&Flow=0 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.tsetmc.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Referer: http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=151915
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fa;q=0.8

* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: public, no-cache="Set-Cookie"
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Encoding: gzip
< Expires: Tue, 03 Nov 2020 02:03:15 GMT
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
< Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=34cwudfw41fkvibcksu45lnt; domain=.tsetmc.com; path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
< Date: Tue, 03 Nov 2020 02:03:06 GMT
< Content-Length: 16989
<
* Connection #0 to host www.tsetmc.com left intact

Done. (121808 B)

Pinging WIN-G2AELSC5ER9 [::1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms

Ping statistics for ::1:
    Packets: Sent = 10, Received = 10, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

2020-11-03 -  5:29:33
*   Trying 185.117.204.245:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.tsetmc.com (185.117.204.245) port 80 (#0)
> GET /Loader.aspx?ParTree=151313&Flow=0 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.tsetmc.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Referer: http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=151915
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fa;q=0.8

* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: public, no-cache="Set-Cookie"
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Encoding: gzip
< Expires: Tue, 03 Nov 2020 01:59:42 GMT
< Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=03ymtrwh14eqgxyii1ryijvr; domain=.tsetmc.com; path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
< Content-Security-policy: defult-Src 'self'
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Farams-Options: DENY
< X-XSS-Protection:  1; mode=block
< Date: Tue, 03 Nov 2020 01:59:33 GMT
< Content-Length: 16989
<
* Connection #0 to host www.tsetmc.com left intact

Done. (121808 B)

Pinging WIN-G2AELSC5ER9 [::1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms

Ping statistics for ::1:
    Packets: Sent = 10, Received = 10, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

2020-11-03 -  5:29:43
*   Trying 185.117.204.245:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.tsetmc.com (185.117.204.245) port 80 (#0)
> GET /Loader.aspx?ParTree=151313&Flow=0 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.tsetmc.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Referer: http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=151915
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fa;q=0.8

* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: public, no-cache="Set-Cookie"
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Encoding: gzip
< Expires: Tue, 03 Nov 2020 02:03:50 GMT
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
< Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=wzwab2sgb1ib5afibur0tayf; domain=.tsetmc.com; path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
< Date: Tue, 03 Nov 2020 02:03:42 GMT
< Content-Length: 16989
<
```

Comment: set `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);` and try again, does it make any difference?

Comment: @hanshenrik This is not a reason to freeze like this, do you suppose I set the timeout to 1 second, should I not receive a logical message?

Answer (score 1):

No clue. Seems to be a endless loop with 1 min interval over days am I right?

PHP may need more sleep. Sorry for that joke.

You have written, that you execute your php via cmd. I understand that as you could use a batch file.
So I've got an idea for a possible suggestion / solution / workaround for you:

- Remove the loop from php and make the loop inside a batch file

**batchfile.bat**

```
    @ECHO OFF
    :loop
    echo %date:~0% - %time:~0,8%
    REM !YOUR PHP CALL HERE!
    @ping -n 60 localhost > nul
    cls
    GOTO loop
```

I think you're familiar with php but here the modified code (just remove while and sleep):

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=151313&Flow=0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Connection: keep-alive';
$headers[] = 'Cache-Control: max-age=0';
$headers[] = 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1';
$headers[] = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36';
$headers[] = 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9';
$headers[] = 'Referer: http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=151915';
$headers[] = 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate';
$headers[] = 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fa;q=0.8';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($ch) . PHP_EOL;
}
if (!$result) {
    echo 'Error: No Result.' . PHP_EOL;
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Edit: It's a long long time ago since I use php/curl last time. I can't remember exactly but I thought there was something with curl and sleep. Idk what. Response of request or something like that. From where do you get the output of your curl loop if I may ask? Anyhow I hope my idea is suitable.

If you like to give it a try don't forget to remove "REM".

Comment: Thanks, I tested this and did not get a good result, I added the result at the end of my questions.

Comment: 5:29:24 / 5:29:33 / 5:29:43 - ping should actually pause for a minute and produce no output. how did you start the batch file? And which Windows Version do you have?

Comment: Yeah, I was some changed to `ping -n 10 localhost` but I don't thinks not effective to result. Windows server 2016 Datacenter run on VPS.